# How to do URL-rewriting in Websphere when Angular application is hosted in subdirectory

Tags: java, angular, url-rewriting, deep-linking, websphere-liberty

We're using Websphere to host a series of applications for us:

- We have an API that's hosted at the root, written in Java
- We have an Angular application hosted at /admin
- We have another Angular application hosted at /marketing

My concern is about **deep-linking**.  If a user is at /marketing/products/1, and they refresh their browser or share the link, I need the server to send that route to the correct Angular application so it can be generated correctly.

In a simpler setup, where the Angular application is living at the root, I would use the Java application's web.xml file to redirect traffic to "/".  But in my current scenario, I need traffic for the marketing site to go to "/marketing", not just to "/".  Just like a deep-link from the admin site would need to go to "/admin".

Furthermore, the base URLs for these Angular applications are subject to change, and we also plan to add additional Angular sites to this same server.  So I'm really looking for a solution that can work dynamically and have the server redirect to the first "slug" in the URL rather than matching specific directories.

Any ideas? (And please excuse and correct any misconceptions I've demonstrated above -- I currently know very little about WebSphere)

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple possible ways forward.

1. You could still use the `error-page` directive in `web.xml`, but specify the URL of a servlet in your application that could do the inspection manually and issue a redirect as appropriate. How the list of context roots is provided to your app will differ based on how it's packaged, but it could be done using files, environment variables, or JNDI entries in `server.xml`.
2. If the URLs could be changed, the Angular apps could be changed to use [`HashLocationStrategy`](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy) in their routers which would sidestep the error page. It doesn't seem likely that that's the case but I'll put it here to get it out of the way.
3. You could consider splitting each Angular app into its own `.war` file and configuring the context root in the [`webApplication`](https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/config/#webApplication.html) element in `server.xml`. Then redirecting to `/` in `web.xml` would work since that / is relative to the context-root.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions!  I'll start digging into them and see what happens.

Comment: These were great suggestions, and I ended up working a bit on the first two but couldn't quite get them to work.  I also attempted to convert the applications to Angular Universal apps, but had issues with that as well.  I finally settled on combining the Angular apps into a single application.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

We ended up combining those separate Angular applications into 1 so that WebSphere could direct everything to "/" and Angular routing could handle everything from there.